# Can't verticaly align an image within a navigation bar with the rest of the menu

Tags: html, css, alignment, nav

I have this navigation bar:

```
    <ul>
        <li class="logo-container"><a href="#"><img src="frontend/images/3.svg"></a></li>

        <li class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Work With Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

and i want the logo (the "logo-container") to be vertically aligned to the rest of the navigation elements

Relevant css:

```
.logo-container{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    margin: auto;
}

.logo-container img {
    width: 35%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

I have tried display: inline & line height the same of the nave height, tried both padding and margin top, but it moves the rest of the navigation down...

[Click here for the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5QMjF/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would vertical-align:middle; to your `<li>` set as `display:inline-block;`  will do ?
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5QMjF/1/)**

By defaut, inline-boxe are set on the baseline. (`vertical-align:baseline;`)

Comment: @CharlesWyke-Smith i did, and once the waiting period is over will accept!

Answer (score 0):

Set the class `.logo-container img` as `display: inline-block;`

You can also set it as `vertical-align:middle;` or `top;` or `bottom;` depending on where you want the image to be.